# How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked or UploadedFile is null / throws an error / not usable

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to upload a file using PrimeFaces, but the `fileUploadListener` method isn't being invoked after the upload finishes.

Here is the view:

```
<h:form>
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"
        mode="advanced" 
        update="messages"
        sizeLimit="100000" 
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>

    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
</h:form>
```

And the bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class FileUploadController {

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

}
```

I've placed a breakpoint on the method, but it's never called. When using `mode="simple"` and `ajax="false"`, it is been invoked, but I want it to work in the advanced mode. I'm using Netbeans and Glassfish 3.1.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

How to configure and troubleshoot `<p:fileUpload>` depends on PrimeFaces and JSF version.

### All PrimeFaces versions

The below requirements apply to all PrimeFaces versions:

1. The `enctype` attribute of the `<h:form>` needs to be set to `multipart/form-data`. When this is absent, the ajax upload may just work, but the general browser behavior is unspecified and dependent on form composition and webbrowser make/version. Just always specify it to be on the safe side.
2. When using `mode="advanced"` (i.e. ajax upload, this is the default), then make sure that you've a `<h:head>` in the (master) template. This will ensure that the necessary JavaScript files are properly included. This is not required for `mode="simple"` (non-ajax upload), but this would break look'n'feel and functionality of all other PrimeFaces components, so you don't want to miss that anyway.
3. When using `mode="simple"` (i.e. non-ajax upload), then ajax must be disabled on any PrimeFaces command buttons/links by `ajax="false"`, and you must use `<p:fileUpload value>` with `<p:commandButton action>` instead of `<p:fileUpload listener>`.

So, if you want (auto) file upload with ajax support (mind the `<h:head>`!):

```xml
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload listener="#{bean.upload}" auto="true" /> // For PrimeFaces version older than 8.x this should be fileUploadListener instead of listener.
</h:form>
```

```java
public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();
    String fileName = uploadedFile.getFileName();
    String contentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();
    byte[] contents = uploadedFile.getContents(); // Or getInputStream()
    // ... Save it, now!
}
```

Or if you want non-ajax file upload:

```xml
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload mode="simple" value="#{bean.uploadedFile}" />
    <p:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{bean.upload}" ajax="false" />
</h:form>
```

```java
private transient UploadedFile uploadedFile; // +getter+setter

public void upload() {
    String fileName = uploadedFile.getFileName();
    String contentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();
    byte[] contents = uploadedFile.getContents(); // Or getInputStream()
    // ... Save it, now!
}
```

Do note that ajax-related attributes such as `auto`, `allowTypes`, `update`, `onstart`, `oncomplete`, etc are **ignored** in `mode="simple"`. So it's needless to specify them in such case.

Also note that the `UploadedFile` property is declared `transient` just to raise awareness that this is absolutely not serializable. The whole thing should be placed in a request scoped bean instead of a view or even session scoped one. If this is the case, then you can safely remove the `transient` attribute.

Also note that you should **immediately read and save the file contents** inside the abovementioned methods and not in a different bean method invoked by a later HTTP request. This is because technically speaking the uploaded file contents is request scoped and thus unavailable in a later/different HTTP request. Any attempt to read it in a later request will most likely end up with `java.io.FileNotFoundException` on the temporary file and only cause confusion.

---

### PrimeFaces 8.x or newer

Configuration is identical to the 5.x version info below, but if your listener is not called, check if the method attribute is called `listener` and not `fileUploadListener` like as in versions before 8.x.

---

### PrimeFaces 5.x

This does **not** require any additional configuration if you're using at least JSF 2.2 and your `faces-config.xml` is also declared conform at least JSF 2.2 version. You do **not** need the PrimeFaces file upload filter at all and you also do **not** need the `primefaces.UPLOADER` context parameter in `web.xml`. In case it's unclear to you how to properly install and configure JSF depending on the target server used, head to [How to properly install and configure JSF libraries via Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081234/how-to-properly-install-and-configure-jsf-libraries-via-maven) and ["Installing JSF" section of our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).

If you're however not using JSF 2.2 yet and you can't upgrade JSF 2.0/2.1 to 2.2 yet (should be effortless though when already on a Servlet 3.0 compatible container), then you need to manually register the below PrimeFaces file upload filter in `web.xml` (it will parse the multi part request and fill the regular request parameter map so that `FacesServlet` can continue working as usual):

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>primeFacesFileUploadFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>primeFacesFileUploadFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

The `<servlet-name>` value of `facesServlet` must match exactly the value in the `<servlet>` entry of the `javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet` in the same `web.xml`. So if it's e.g. `Faces Servlet`, then you need to edit it accordingly to match.

---

### PrimeFaces 4.x

The same story as PrimeFaces 5.x applies on 4.x as well.

There's only a potential problem in getting the uploaded file content by `UploadedFile#getContents()`. This will return `null` when native API is used instead of Apache Commons FileUpload. You need to use `UploadedFile#getInputStream()` instead. See also [How to insert uploaded image from p:fileUpload as BLOB in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305633/how-to-insert-uploaded-image-from-pfileupload-as-blob-in-mysql/8310773#8310773)

Another potential problem with native API will manifest is when the upload component is present in a form on which a different "regular" ajax request is fired which does not process the upload component. See also [File upload doesn't work with AJAX in PrimeFaces 4.0/JSF 2.2.x - javax.servlet.ServletException: The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262356/file-upload-doesnt-work-with-ajax-in-primefaces-4-0-jsf-2-2-x-javax-servlet-s).

Both problems can also be solved by switching to Apache Commons FileUpload. See PrimeFaces 3.x section for detail.

---

### PrimeFaces 3.x

This version does not support JSF 2.2 / Servlet 3.0 native file upload. You need to manually install Apache Commons FileUpload and explicitly register the file upload filter in `web.xml`.

You need the following libraries:

- [`commons-fileupload.jar`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload)
- [`commons-io.jar`](http://commons.apache.org/io)

Those must be present in the webapp's runtime classpath. When using Maven, make sure they are at least runtime scoped (default scope of compile is also good). When manually carrying around JARs, make sure they end up in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

The file upload filter registration detail can be found in PrimeFaces 5.x section here above. In case you're using PrimeFaces 4+ and you'd like to explicitly use Apache Commons FileUpload instead of JSF 2.2 / Servlet 3.0 native file upload, then you need next to the mentioned libraries and filter also the below context param in `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>commons</param-value><!-- Allowed values: auto, native and commons. -->
</context-param>
```

---

### Troubleshooting

In case it still doesn't work, here are another possible causes unrelated to PrimeFaces configuration:

1. Only if you're using the PrimeFaces file upload filter: There's another `Filter` in your webapp which runs *before* the PrimeFaces file upload filter and has already consumed the request body by e.g. calling `getParameter()`, `getParameterMap()`, `getReader()`, etcetera. A request body can be parsed only once. When you call one of those methods before the file upload filter does its job, then the file upload filter will get an empty request body.

   To fix this, you'd need to put the `<filter-mapping>` of the file upload filter *before* the other filter in `web.xml`. If the request is not a `multipart/form-data` request, then the file upload filter will just continue as if nothing happened. If you use filters that are automagically added because they use annotations (e.g. PrettyFaces), you might need to add explicit ordering via web.xml. See [How to define servlet filter order of execution using annotations in WAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560969/how-to-define-servlet-filter-order-of-execution-using-annotations-in-war)
2. Only if you're using the PrimeFaces file upload filter: There's another `Filter` in your webapp which runs *before* the PrimeFaces file upload filter and has performed a [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) call. Usually, URL rewrite filters such as [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) do this. This triggers the `FORWARD` dispatcher, but filters listen by default on `REQUEST` dispatcher only.

   To fix this, you'd need to either put the PrimeFaces file upload filter *before* the forwarding filter, or to reconfigure the PrimeFaces file upload filter to listen on `FORWARD` dispatcher too:

   ```xml
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>primeFacesFileUploadFilter</filter-name>
       <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
       <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
       <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```
3. There's a nested `<h:form>`. This is illegal in HTML and the browser behavior is unspecified. More than often, the browser won't send the expected data on submit. Make sure that you are not nesting `<h:form>`. This is completely regardless of the form's `enctype`. Just do not nest forms at all.

If you're still having problems, well, debug the HTTP traffic. Open the webbrowser's developer toolset (press F12 in Chrome/Firebug23+/IE9+) and check the Net/Network section. If the HTTP part looks fine, then debug the JSF code. Put a breakpoint on [`FileUploadRenderer#decode()`](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/fileupload/FileUploadRenderer.java) and advance from there.

---

### Saving uploaded file

After you finally got it to work, your next question shall probably be like "How/where do I save the uploaded file?". Well, continue here: [How to save uploaded file in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211843/how-to-save-uploaded-file-in-jsf).

Answer (score 30):

You are using prettyfaces too? Then set dispatcher to FORWARD:

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: This is still an issue when used with OCP Rewrite. I owe you a beer :)

Answer (score 7):

One point I noticed with Primefaces 3.4 and Netbeans 7.2:

Remove the Netbeans auto-filled parameters for function handleFileUpload i.e. (event) otherwise event could be null.

```
<h:form>
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload(event)}"
        mode="advanced" 
        update="messages"
        sizeLimit="100000" 
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>

    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR must not be equal to _

Comment: Could you elaborate, please?!

Answer (score 1):

Putting `p:fileUpload` inside a `h:form` solved the problem at my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with primefaces 5.3 and I went through all the points described by BalusC with no result. I followed his advice of debugging FileUploadRenderer#decode() and I discovered that my web.xml was unproperly set

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
  <param-value>auto|native|commons</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**The param-value must be 1 of these 3 values but not all of them!!** The whole context-param section can be removed and the default will be ***auto***

Answer (score 0):

bean.xhtml

```
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">    
<p:outputLabel value="Choose your file" for="submissionFile" />
                <p:fileUpload id="submissionFile"
                    value="#{bean.file}"
                    fileUploadListener="#{bean.uploadFile}" mode="advanced"
                    auto="true" dragDropSupport="false" update="messages"
                    sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="1" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/" />

</h:form>
```

Bean.java

```
@ManagedBean
```

@ViewScoped
public class Submission implements Serializable {

```
private UploadedFile file;

//Gets
//Sets

public void uploadFasta(FileUploadEvent event) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {

    String content = IOUtils.toString(event.getFile().getInputstream(), "UTF-8");

    String filePath = PATH + "resources/submissions/" + nameOfMyFile + ".pdf";

    MyFileWriter.writeFile(filePath, content);

    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
            event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.", null);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);

}
```

}

web.xml

```
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is an answer? It is only code, not explanation or whatever

Comment: "#{bean.uploadFile}"  vs "#{bean.uploadFasta}" , remove update="messages" and it will (only) that works for me !

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the suggestions here were helpful for me. So I had to debug primefaces and found the reason of the problem was:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No multipart config for servlet fileUpload
```

Then I have added  section into my faces servlet in the web.xml. So that has fixed the problem:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>

        <servlet-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <multipart-config>
            <location>/tmp</location>
            <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>
    </servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, due to the fact that I had all the configuration that describe in this post, but in my case was because I had two jQuery imports (one of them was PrimeFaces's bundled jQuery) which caused conflicts to upload files.

[Manually adding / loading jQuery with PrimeFaces results in Uncaught TypeErrors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166039/manually-adding-loading-jquery-with-primefaces-results-in-uncaught-typeerrors)

Comment: Didn't you get a specific error in the browser developer console then?

Comment: @Kukeltje this is what the console showed:                                     
   Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fileupload'

Answer (score 0):

For people using Tomee or Tomcat and can't get it working, try to create **context.xml** in **META-INF** and add **allowCasualMultipartParsing="true"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context allowCasualMultipartParsing="true">
  <!-- empty or not depending your project -->
</Context>
```

Comment: This is a work around for a wrong filter configuration/ordering.

Comment: Hi @BalusC, can you give us more explanation? Is there a better way than this work around?

Comment: See my answer in this question.

Answer (score 0):

With JBoss 7.2(Undertow) and PrimeFaces 6.0 org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter should be removed from web.xml and context param file uploader should be set to native:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>native</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Should? Do you get **specific errors** if you don't?

Comment: Yes, my FileUploadEvent doesn't invoke without this changes.

Comment: That is not an explicit error, that is unexpected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

In my application it worked apparently at random, in some startups it worked in others it didn't work.  I have a java configuration, in a class which extends org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.

This is how I added the filters:

```
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
       ...
       ServletRegistration.Dynamic facesServlet = servletContext.addServlet("Faces Servlet", new FacesServlet());
       facesServlet.addMapping("*.xhtml");
       ...
       EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST,DispatcherType.FORWARD);
       FileUploadFilter fileUploadFilter = new FileUploadFilter();
       FilterRegistration.Dynamic primeFacesFUF = servletContext.addFilter("PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter", fileUploadFilter);
       primeFacesFUF.addMappingForServletNames(dispatcherTypes, false, "Faces Servlet");
       servletContext.addFilter(..others filters
```

The PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter was added first in the code.

I solved by commenting the following instructions and now it always works:

```
 @Override
            public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
               ...
//      ServletRegistration.Dynamic facesServlet = servletContext.addServlet("Faces Servlet", new FacesServlet());
//        facesServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
//        facesServlet.addMapping("*.xhtml");
               ...
               EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST,DispatcherType.FORWARD);
              //        FileUploadFilter fileUploadFilter = new FileUploadFilter();
//        FilterRegistration.Dynamic primeFacesFUF = servletContext.addFilter("PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter", fileUploadFilter);
//        primeFacesFUF.addMappingForServletNames(dispatcherTypes, false, "Faces Servlet");
               servletContext.addFilter(..others filters
```

p.s. I also realized that the problem did not only concern "p:fileUpload" but all forms of the "enctype="multipart/form-data" type