# p:fileUpload prime faces

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

The listener doesn't respond to my action:

```xml
<h:form>
    <p:fileUpload mode="simple" fileUploadListener="#{ADD.uploadImage}" auto="true"/>
</h:form>
```

and here is the backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestClass {

    public void uploadImage(FileUploadEvent e){
        System.out.println("EVENT");
    }

}
```

and here is my web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
            <param-value>51200</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
            <param-value>/tmpDir3/</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The problem is that the method `uploadImage` doesn't get called.

What is wrong with my code or what is missing?

Comment: is your form got enctype="multipart/form-data" , like this : <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: i have this exception in log tomcat

01/04/2012 01:00:57 م org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/UploadedImageTest] threw exception
java.io.IOException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. \tmpDir\upload__5e4873ce_1366d8db020__8000_00000020.tmp (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: yes i have this line in my form

Comment: it can't find your upload dir... try changing into <param-value>/tmpDir3</param-value>  (removed one / )

Comment: nothing ,doesnt effect
<init-param>
            <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
            <param-value>/tmpDir</param-value>
        </init-param>

Comment: take a look at this detailed answer.... http://stackoverflow.com/a/8880083/617373

Comment: Are you looking at the right bean? Your binding says `#{ADD.uploadImage}`, but the bean you've shown will be called `testClass`, NOT `ADD`.

Comment: yes it is my mistake when i post this issue into web

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked)

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `@ManagedBean` annotation, the name of the instances of your bean will be the name of your class (with a lower-case first letter). In your example, as the name of your class is `TestClass`, the name of your bean will be `testClass`.

So, when you write an EL expression that should invoke a method on this bean, you have to write `#{testClass.myMethod}` (in your case, this will be `#{testClass.uploadImage}`.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html