# upload file example with primefaces jsf2

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, netbeans-7

I looked every where for a working example of uploading a file with jsf 2 and primefaces and I tried so many alternatives but it is still not working 
I added the filter in the web.xml then i created the managed bean with its listener method and finally added the

```
 <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"/>
```

as it's shown in the official site of primefaces [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf).

I also added the commons-file and common-io jars

No results thus far, what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Please check if your question is not already been answered by this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked/8880083#8880083

Comment: You might want to edit your question for clarity. Do you have code you can paste that is not working? We may be able to help if you do. I edited your question a bit. If your question requires people to figure out what you MEANT to ask, it will probably be down voted and closed.

Comment: what version of primefaces are you using? did you add enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form?