# Get An Uploaded File Recognized By JSF Project

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish

My question is oriented to the process after the file is uploaded, i mean, i'm using JSF 2.1 and also Primefaces to upload files to my project's folder, but i need to get the file immediately recognized by the project so i can use it or read it to show a kind of preview of the file uploaded, so how do i do this?

Comment: thread [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked) and tutorial [Primefaces file upload example](http://www.mastertheboss.com/primefaces/primefaces-file-upload-example) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which component you are using. The easiest way would be using [Single FileUpload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf):

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileBean.handleFileUpload}"
                          mode="advanced" 
                          sizeLimit="100000"/>
```

after uploading the handleFileUpload method will be called:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    String filename = event.getFile().getFileName();
    String content = new String(event.getFile().getContents());
}
```

As you can see the `filename` and the `content` are both String and it's pretty easy to show some kind of preview after the upload.

For example, you can assign the `content` to another bean property which is connected to a `p:inputTextarea` on your interface. Then by using the `update` attribute of the `p:fileUpload` you can update that particular `p:inputTextarea`.

Comment: that is what i'm doing, but when the file ends up uploading and i try to access it, it does not get recognized, i have to reload the page so i can use it