# How can I upload image using prime faces in jsf

Tags: jsf, upload, primefaces

I have following table

category

catId
 catName
 description
 catImage

I want to create a form to add new category. But I want to use primefaces 3.4.2

For image uploading and wanna store image path in database.

How can I do that using managed bean???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do using managed bean. check the following links

1. Primefaces component suite for [FileUpload - Simple](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/fileUploadSimple.jsf)
2. A Stackoverflow answer [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked/8880083#8880083)