# PrimeFaces p:fileUpload does not invoke method

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I'm trying to use PrimeFaces `<p:fileUpload>`. I have it setup, very much the same as [the showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf), but it does not work. I never get the successful message. I get no errors or anything.

Here's my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
            <param-value>51200</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
            <param-value>C:\etc</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here's the view:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head></h:head>

    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"
                      mode="advanced" 
                      update="messages"
                      sizeLimit="100000" 
                      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>

        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
    </h:form>

</html>

    </h:form>
  </h:body>
```

Here's the bean:

```
package fileUpload;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;

@ManagedBean(name = "fileUploadController")
public class fileUploadController {

    private String destination = "c:\test";

    public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Success! ", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        // Do what you want with the file        
        try {
            copyFile(event.getFile().getFileName(), event.getFile().getInputstream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {
        try {


            // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination + fileName));

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            System.out.println("New file created!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

What have I missed out?

```
WARNING: PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /FileUpload, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called
WARNING: /index.xhtml @15,63 fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload(event)}": Method handleFileUpload not found
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @15,63 fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload(event)}": Method handleFileUpload not found
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:109)
    at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload.broadcast(FileUpload.java:279)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:759)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:935)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722).
```

Comment: Please check if this doesn't already answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked/8880083#8880083

Comment: Hi there i have tried following the sets in that, but still i can not upload the image, it will let me upload it but there is no successful message or anything so i do not think it is uploading it

Comment: Okay, you have thus also Commons-FileUpload and Commons-IO in webapp's runtime classpath? Your view is by the way quite strange. The form is not in the body. Is this careless preparation for the question or does it reflect the real code?

Comment: i have added Commons-FileUpload and Commons-IO into Web-INF/lib, i have not done anything else with these apart from include them here, i read this should be enought, should i do anything else with these ? i am using netbeans and glassfish

Comment: Check the logs, are you getting any error?

Comment: SEVERE: WebModule[/FileUpload]PWC1270: Exception starting filter PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter

Comment: ok have managed to clear up that error am now getting a new one, updated above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception is self-explaining.

> javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @15,63 fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload(event)}": Method handleFileUpload not found

This method does indeed not exist. It's instead this one:

```
public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {
```

Use either `#{fileUploadController.upload}` or rename the method to `handleFileUpload`.

Comment: Thank you very much:), where are the uploads saved to ? as i did try to save them to c:\test but nothing is here

Comment: Ok got it, c:/test, but now when it trys to save here it says access is denied, can i give it access?