# fileUploadListener="#{imagemBackgroundMB.upload()}": Method not found: br.com.ferpasys.mb.ImagemBackgroundMB@436f4ff8.upload()

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, el

I'm trying to use `<p:fileUpload>`. I followed [this example](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/primefaces/primefaces-file-upload-example).

```
<h:form id="AlteraBackgroundForm">
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{imagemBackgroundMB.upload()}" 
        invalidFileMessage="Imagem inválida! Escolha uma imagem do tipo png"
        invalidSizeMessage="Tamanho máximo da imagem eh 100mb(mega bytes)"                      
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(png)$/" 
        sizeLimit="100000" 
        description="Escolha a imagem"/> 
</h:form>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ImagemBackgroundMB {

    public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

However, it didn't even invoke the method and throws the following exception:

```
ADVERTÊNCIA: /template/alteraBackground.xhtml @25,41 fileUploadListener="#{imagemBackgroundMB.upload()}": Method not found: br.com.ferpasys.mb.ImagemBackgroundMB@436f4ff8.upload()
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /template/alteraBackground.xhtml @25,41 fileUploadListener="#{imagemBackgroundMB.upload()}": Method not found: br.com.ferpasys.mb.ImagemBackgroundMB@436f4ff8.upload()
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:109)
    at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload.broadcast(FileUpload.java:290)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:755)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: solved the problem with tip @BalusC here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014514/primefaces-pfileupload-does-not-invoke-method

Comment: Exactly following the example would also help. You didn't.