# p:fileUpload sometimes fires the handle event sometimes not

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I can successfully upload images in another page, but on a page with below code:

```
<p:fileUpload  id="vendorLogoUpload" fileUploadListener="#{vendorEditController.handleVendorLogo}" mode="advanced" auto="true" 
                                                        update="vendorLogo" sizeLimit="10000000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
```

handleVendorLogo is fired when a dialog first opened, on second try to upload another photo, handle event is not fired. What might this be about?

Comment: Did you saw something in error console, maybe there are some errors with Javascript?

Comment: Did you follow all these requirements? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked

Comment: Have you noticed any pattern at all to the errors?

Comment: @kolossus i do not see any errors on server console or on fiefox debugger firebug

Comment: @partlov i do not see any errors on server console or on fiefox debugger firebug