# Primefaces fileUploadSingle is not displayed

Tags: java, html, spring, jsf, primefaces

I want to use the [fileUploadSingle](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf) in my application:

However, when I added the component. Nothing is diplayed.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">  

    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"  
            mode="advanced"   
            update="messages"  
            sizeLimit="100000"   
            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>  

    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>  

</h:form>
```

I am using:

```
        <junit-version>4.8.2</junit-version>
        <mockito-version>1.9.0</mockito-version>
        <dbunit-version>2.2</dbunit-version>
        <hibernate-version>4.0.1.Final</hibernate-version>
        <hibernate-validator-version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate-validator-version>
        <c3p0-version>0.9.1.2</c3p0-version>
        <spring-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <aspectj-version>1.5.4</aspectj-version>
        <jsf-version>2.1.3_01</jsf-version>
        <primefaces-version>3.0.M1</primefaces-version>
```

I also included the `commons-fileupload` and the `commons-io` in my app. However, nothing is shown on my page

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818. There might be a solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added following code in your web.xml?

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```