# Primefaces (3.5) FileUpload Component Cannot Update Uploaded Filename to OutputText Component

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml, netbeans-7, mojarra

Hi there im using netbeans IDE 7.2, primefaces 3.5, glassfish server 3.1.2, mojarra 2.1.6.

Im using an outputText component to display the name of the uploaded file after uploading. But the outputText component was never updated to display the file name. Pleas help.

Im having this xhtml page:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p:ajaxStatus>
       <f:facet name="start">
           <h:graphicImage value="images/loading.gif" />
       </f:facet>
       <f:facet name="complete">
        <h:outputText value="" />
       </f:facet>
   </p:ajaxStatus>
   <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AttachmentLabel}"/>
   <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{testingPage.handleFileUpload}"
                 allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(doc|docx|ppt|pptx|xls|xlsx|pdf)$/"
                 update="attachmentname"/> 
   <h:outputText value="#{bundle.AttachmentLabel} #{bundle.YangLabel} #{bundle.AlreadyLabel} #{bundle.UploadedLabel}"/>
   <h:outputText id="attachmentname" value="{testingPage.attachmentfilename}"/>                            
</h:form>
```

And this is my ViewScoped backing bean's handleFileUpload listener:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
try {
       LogController.log.info("Assign attachment variable to event file property");
       attachment = event.getFile();
       LogController.log.info("Assign attachment byte to attachment contents");
       attachmentbyte = attachment.getContents();
       LogController.log.info("Assign attachment file name to attachment file name");
       attachmentfilename = attachment.getFileName();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       LogController.log.fatal(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

What could be wrong? The primefaces showcase is working perfectly. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked)

Comment: Your listener is not being called. If you add `mode = "simple"` it will work. Go through the answer above to find the possible cause.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks. Yup I've been there, previously my listener was never invoked. But I've put in the required libraries and I've also rearrange my filters in web.xml. Upon debugging, the listener is invoked accordingly, it is indeed invoked. And attachmentfilename = attachment.getFileName(); line is also executed and the variable contain the uploaded file name. But it is not updated into the outputText component. Hope you can help.

Comment: That is interesting. Try to add `prependId = "false"` on the form...I doubt it'll work because you would have gotten an error. Also, is this a standalone form or in a template ?

Comment: Another thing you could try is `update = @form`. Let me know how this turns out for you.