# Deploy error in Glassfish - PrimeFaces

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

Everything works fine when I run my project in NetBeans, but when I try to deploy it I get the following error:

```
Error occurred during deployment: 

Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:
ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
java.lang.RuntimeException:
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Source Document:
jar:file:/C:/Users/User/Downloads/glassfish-4.0/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/Zaman/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.4.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer'
is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem. Please see server.log for more
details.
```

It says that the cause is:

```
Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer'
is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.
```

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add [Commons Fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) to your application.

Comment: Thanks. It helped. App deployed witout any problem. but, now it is saying taht, after launching it. `If the server or listener is not running, the link may not work. In this event, check the status of the server instance. After launching the web application, use the browser's Back button to return to this screen.`

Comment: Seems like a different problem, worth a different question.

Comment: Thanks anyway. At last it is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked or UploadedFile is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked)

You must add [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) and [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) to your classpath