# Primefaces fileUpload error with layoutUnit

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using a Layout structure that has centerLayout, westLayout. In center layoutUnit is used primefaces fileupload. I added filter to web.xml and fileupload required lib to WEB/INF lib.

I implemented the steps in that link : [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked or UploadedFile is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked)
It does not work for my problem.

When layoutComplex.xhtml page is load, take following error:"**/UI Layout Initialization Error. The center-pane element does not exist. The-center pane is a required element." 
"Error Rendering View[/layoutComplex.xhtml]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed"**

If I write to address bar "http:....hostName/portal/dataImportingProjectCurrent.jsf" url, there is no error.

in layoutComplex.xhtml code part :

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center" id="centerLayout">

                <h:form id="formCenter" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p:panel id="optionPanel">
                        <p:panel id="panelWelcome"
                            rendered="#{menuSelection.selectedOption == menuSelection.WELCOME}">
                            <ui:include src="/welcomePage.xhtml" />
                        </p:panel>

                        <p:panel id="panelUserAdd"
                            rendered="#{menuSelection.selectedOption == menuSelection.USER_ADD}">
                            <ui:include src="/kullanici.xhtml" />
                        </p:panel>
                        <p:panel id="panelProjectAdd"
                            rendered="#{menuSelection.selectedOption == menuSelection.PROJECT_ADD}">
                            <ui:include src="/proje.xhtml" />
                        </p:panel>

                            <p:panel id="panelAuthorizationAdd" 
                            rendered="#{menuSelection.selectedOption == menuSelection.AUTHORIZATION_ADD}">
                            <ui:include src="/yetki.xhtml" />
                        </p:panel>

                        <p:panel id="panelRoleAdd"
                            rendered="#{menuSelection.selectedOption == menuSelection.ROL_ADD}">
                            <ui:include src="/rol.xhtml" />
                        </p:panel>

                        <p:panel id="panelDataDefining"
                            rendered="#{menuSelection.selectedOption == menuSelection.DATA_DEFINING}">
                            <ui:include src="/dataDefining.xhtml" />
                        </p:panel>

                        <p:panel id="panelDataEvaluation"
                            rendered="#{menuSelection.selectedOption == menuSelection.DATA_EVALUATION}">
                            <ui:include src="/dataEvaluation.xhtml" />
                        </p:panel>
                        **<p:panel id="panelDataImporting"
                            rendered="#{menuSelection.selectedOption == menuSelection.DATA_IMPORTING}">
                            <ui:include src="/dataImporting.xhtml" />
                        </p:panel>**
                        <p:panel id="panelDataReporting"
                            rendered="#{menuSelection.selectedOption == menuSelection.DATA_REPORTING}">
                            <ui:include src="/dataReporting.xhtml" />
                        </p:panel>
                        <p:panel id="panelAdmin"
                            rendered="#{menuSelection.selectedOption == menuSelection.ADMIN}">
                            <ui:include src="/admin.xhtml" />
                        </p:panel>
                        <p:panel id="panelCreateNewReportSchema"
                            rendered="#{menuSelection.selectedOption == menuSelection.DATA_REPORTING_NEW_SCHEMA}">
                            <ui:include src="/dataReportingNewSchema.xhtml" />
                        </p:panel>
                        <p:panel id="panelCreateReport"
                            rendered="#{menuSelection.selectedOption == menuSelection.DATA_REPORT_CREATING}">
                            <ui:include src="/dataReportCreating.xhtml" />
                        </p:panel>

                    </p:panel>
                </h:form>

            </p:layoutUnit>
```

Page code that belongs primefaces fileUpload is dataImportingProjectCurrent.xhtml:

```
<h:body>
<h:form id="formDataImportProjectCurrent" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <h1>
        Project current fdasdata importinfdsa  is under construction. Coming soon...
    </h1>

    <p:fileUpload label="Seçiniz"
            fileUploadListener="#{dataImportingBean.handleFileUpload}"
            mode="advanced" auto="true" sizeLimit="1000000"
            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />

</h:form>
```

My bean is DataImportingBean.java :

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DataImportingBean extends GenericBean implements Serializable{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 730586496885706439L;

private UploadedFile file;

@Inject
DataImportingService DataImportingService;

@Override
public GenericService<Data, Long> getService() {
    return DataImportingService;
}


@Override
public void newObject() {
    setObject(new Data());
}


public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {  
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    System.err.println("event.getFile().getFileName(): " + event.getFile().getFileName());
}
```

}

Thank you very much for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is work after add following context parameter to web.xml. Thanks

```
<context-param>
<param-name>com.sun.faces.writeStateAtFormEnd</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```