# PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked

Tags: java, file, jsf, primefaces, glassfish

I´m trying to implement a fileuploader. I´m using java 7, primefaces 4 and glassfish 3.1.2
I tried following the indications in the accepted answer for the post [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked or UploadedFile is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked/8880083#8880083)
Without success.
Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

          <!-- Spring Context Configuration' s Path definition -->
          <context-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
         </param-value>
      </context-param>

      <!-- The Bootstrap listener to start up and shut down Spring's root WebApplicationContext. It is registered to Servlet Container -->
      <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
      </listener>
      <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
      </listener>

     <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- JSF Servlet is defined to container -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Mapping with servlet and url for the http requests. -->
     <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

     <welcome-file-list>  
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>  
     </welcome-file-list>  

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>          
</web-app>
```

heres is my .xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="../template/Layout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <div class="frame">
                <h:form id="originadorForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" life="3000" />
                    <p:fileUpload label="Cargar Imagen" fileUploadListener="#{originadorMB.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" update="growl" auto="true" sizeLimit="100000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>                    
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and heres is my method inside my managed bean that will do the upload:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Exito", event.getFile().getFileName() + " fue subido. " + selectedOriginadoresListDTO.getImagen());
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>" + selectedOriginadoresListDTO.getImagen() + " && " + event.getFile().getFileName());
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

the problem is that my method never gets called. I added the encrypt in my form and I added the filters to my `web.xml` without success at all.
What am I doing wrong????
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you doing to encrypt?

Comment: I´m not encrypting anything but if you are refering to encypt I´m using:  <h:form id="originadorForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: for the uploading process to work you must add commons-fileupload.jar, commons-io-.jar to your web-inf/lib folder

Comment: I´m working with maven so I added them inside my pom and then I built because if I didn´t; then it wouldn´t compile.

Comment: If you didn't compile then it wouldn't work.