# How can I use <p:fileUpload> with mode simple and ajax="true"?

Tags: ajax, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to upload a file with use of PrimeFaces and a ManagedBean. I want use `p:fileUpload` with mode="simple".

**XHTML Code:**

```
    <p:fileUpload id="fileId" mode="simple" value="#{itemBean.upFile}"
        fileLimit="1" />
    <p:commandButton ajax="true" value="Upload File" update="messagess"
                     id="save-btn"
                     actionListener="#{itemBean.fileUpload(itemBean.upFile,itemBean.hiddenFileName)}"
                     process="@this" oncomplete="showImage()" />
```

**ManagedBean:**

```
public void fileUpload(UploadedFile uploadFile, String hiddenKey) {  
    String keyFileName = hiddenKey;

    boolean validFile = true;
    String expression = "([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(gif|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|PNG|GIF|JPG|JPEG|bmp))$)";
    if((uploadFile == null) ) {
        validFile = false;
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Error! "+ "Please select an image.");  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }  
    else {
    System.out.println("going to file upload"+uploadFile.getFileName()+"---hiddenKey"+keyFileName);
    if((!uploadFile.getFileName().matches(expression)) ) {
        validFile = false;
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Error! "+ uploadFile.getFileName() + " is not an image.");  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
    if(uploadFile.getSize() > 1000000) {
        validFile = false;
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Error! "+ uploadFile.getFileName() + " size is too large.");  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    if (validFile) {
        // Do what you want with the file        
        try {
            //String extn =uploadFile.getFileName().substring(uploadFile.getFileName().lastIndexOf("."));


            copyFile(uploadFile.getFileName(), uploadFile.getInputstream());

            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Success! "+ uploadFile.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Error! "+ uploadFile.getFileName()+ " not uploaded.");  
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

My problem is, that I clicked on the command button and method in the backing bean is not called.
If I use `ajax="false"` the method is called, but the page got refreshed.

How can I use `ajax="true"` and `<p:fileUpload>` together?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly set `ajax=true` on `commandButton`. It's by default `ajax=true` even you set or not.Try removing `ajax=true`. And `actionListner` needs to be associate to `ActionEvent`

Answer (score 11):

The `<p:fileUpload mode="simple">` doesn't support ajax. Sorry, but this is end of story.

If switching to the ajax-compatible `<p:fileUpload mode="advanced">` is really not an option, then your best bet is upgrading to JSF 2.2 and use its new native `<h:inputFile>` component instead. It also shows up in browser default look'n'feel and is capable of simulating the ajax experience via a hidden iframe trick.

#### See also:

- [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked or UploadedFile is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked/8880083#8880083)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, those two arguments in your `fileUpload()` action method are completely unnecessary. Just the

```
action="#{itemBean.fileUpload}"
```

with

```
public void fileUpload() {
    // ...
}
```

works as good once you remove `process="@this"` attribute.

Comment: simulating the ajax experience via a hidden iframe trick? Could you explain this? thanks