# Primefaces fileUploadListener not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I tried to upload a file with primefaces into my tomcat7 server. I'm using primfaces4. file upload listener doesn't call `handleFileUpload` and hiii not apeared in console
my bean is this:

```
package Pin;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload;
import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

import Util.U;
@ManagedBean(name="pinBean")
@SessionScoped
public class PinBean{
    private UploadedFile file;
    public PinBean(){

        U.wl("Start");
    }
    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        U.wl("get");
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        U.wl("set");
        this.file = file;
    }
    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        UploadedFile file = event.getFile();
        U.wl("hiii");
        //application code
        }


}
```

and my xhtml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form>
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{pinBean.handleFileUpload}" auto="true" mode="advanced"/>
</h:form>
</h:form>
</html>
```

and web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>testUpload</display-name>
  <filter>

<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
<param-value>2097152</param-value>
</init-param>     
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping> 
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8880083/1391249).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finaly it worked, I used simple type of upload.
Important thing:

1- `<h:head></h:head>` was necessary

2- this is necessary in web.xml:

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>commons</param-value>
  </context-param>

 <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

3- in `h:form` it's important to write `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

4- `ajax="false"` for the command button is necessary

I used the simple upload type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p:fileUpload value="#{pinBean.file}" mode="simple" />
<p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false"/>
</h:form>

</html>
```

and my bean is:

```
package Pin;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload;
import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

import Util.U;
@ManagedBean(name="pinBean")
@SessionScoped
public class PinBean{
    private UploadedFile file;
    public PinBean(){

        U.wl("Start");
    }
    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        U.wl("get");
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        U.wl("set");
            this.file = file;
        }
}
```

and my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WebOffice</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>commons</param-value>
  </context-param>

 <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
    the rendered HTML output.
    If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
    that submits the corresponding form.
    If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
    will be added as url parameters.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
    i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
    influence the HTML code.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
    former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
    with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
    if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
    Default is 'false'
</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>Filters</filter-name>
    <filter-class>UserManagement.LoginFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filters</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/not_exist.jsf</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/exception.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this because I also got same problem before

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {

    System.out.println("calling file upload...");
    File targetFolder = new File(Properties.File_Uploaded_path

    + File.separator);

    if (!targetFolder.exists()) {
        targetFolder.mkdirs();
    }
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = event.getFile().getInputstream();

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(targetFolder,
                event.getFile().getFileName()));

        int read = 0;

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {

            out.write(bytes, 0, read);

        }
        inputStream.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("file upload after catch..");
    employeeFileUploadPaths[employeeFileCount] = targetFolder
            .getAbsolutePath()
            + File.separator
            + event.getFile().getFileName();
    System.out.println("empFileUploadPaths[check]"
            + employeeFileUploadPaths[employeeFileCount]);
    employeeFileCount++;

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile()
            .getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    System.out.println("last line of file upload....");
}
```

And In Xhtml page:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form enctype="multipart-data">
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{employeeBean.handleFileUpload}"
                        required="true" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
                        multiple="true" sizeLimit="1000000" fileLimit="5" update="messages"
                        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx)$/">
                        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
                    </p:fileUpload>


                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton value="Add" ajax="false"
                            action="#{employeeBean.addEmployee}">

                        </p:commandButton>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </f:view>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

And Add this in pom.xml Dont remove Primefaces 4.0 Dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: @BehnamSafari I think you have already if you want I can provide you

Comment: I am completely confused, I removed that project, open new one and got new Errors!