# JSF 2.2 file upload and Pretty Faces issue

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2.2, prettyfaces

I am using JSF 2.2 in a WildFly 8.0.0.Final with Pretty Faces 2.0.11.Final.

When I turn pretty-faces on, the upload stops working.

Here is the pretty faces config:

```
<url-mapping id="test">
    <pattern value="/test" />
    <view-id value="/test.jsf" />
</url-mapping>
```

And the form:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile value="#{test.part}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{test.test()}" />
</h:form>
```

The web.xml and faces-config.xml are empty.

Any guesses on how to solve it? Any workarounds?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245691/jsf-2-2-hinputfile-not-working-with-pretty-faces) is pretty similar, but it has no answers.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try my solution:
[Fileupload and PrettyFaces and JSF 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943066/fileupload-and-prettyfaces-and-jsf-2-2)

It should work with all servers.