# Fileupload and PrettyFaces and JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2.2, prettyfaces

I've tried the solution from:
[Primefaces FileUpload with PrettyFaces and JSF 2.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492015/primefaces-fileupload-with-prettyfaces-and-jsf-2-2-3)

But it doesn't work for a few files (tested under tomcat 7.0.50).

One of the files is:
http://ftp.carnet.hr/misc/apache//xerces/j/source/Xerces-J-src.2.11.0-xml-schema-1.1-beta.zip

Has someone a better solution for this problem (other than removing the urlmapping)?

EDIT:
There is no error/exception thrown!
File is shown in the PrimeFaces FileUpload, but the listener is not fired!
JSF2.2 inputFile doesn't work, too!

Comment: Can you give more details about the problem you face, such as the error you get?

Comment: This question is not answered at all with the above mentioned question. This question is not talking about primefaces just pretty and jsf 2.2 fileUpload.

Answer (score 7):

I've found a solution for my problem.

The problem is the action attribute of the forms which are used for the upload.
PrettyFaces changes the action attribute to the new pretty-url.

If you change the action attribute to the real url (the one with .xhtml,.jsf,...) the fileupload works again and the allowCasualMultipartParsing="true" entry in the context-file(tomcat) is not needed anymore.

To change the path place this script into the view (your xhtml-file; jquery needed):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("form[enctype='multipart/form-data']").attr("action","#{request.contextPath}/test/fileupload.xhtml");
    });
</script>
```

Now the fileupload is working for all of my files including the ones which not worked (even with allowCasualMultipartParsing="true" solution).

Tested with Primefaces4.0 FileUpload-Component.

EDIT:
Is there any other better solution?

Comment: I had the same problem, and I also saw that problem. I am using JSF 2.2.x and in that case, use the pastrought with prefix "a". To the form I add to action and the url that you put in your script. Example: <h:form a:action="#{request.contextPath}/test/fileupload.xhtml""></h:form>

Comment: It looks your suggestion is the only one if we want to keep both the rewrite facility and the jsf fileUpload as well. Thanks for it and also to @Marco Lopez.

Answer (score 0):

On my similar project (JSF+JQuery+PrettyFaces/Rewrite), the action and listener functions were called, but the setPart(Part part) function wasn't called (h:inputFile value="#{bean.part}).

I found two solutions, one was to add @MultipartConfig (and @WebServlet + extends HttpServlet) to beans that received upload Part files. However, just adding the allowCasualMultipartParsing="true" entry was sufficient for my project.