# File upload via h:inputfile (prettyfaces) does not work

Tags: jsf, file-upload, glassfish, jsf-2.2, prettyfaces

I'm trying to upload a file to the glassfish application server (v4.1) via `h:inputfile`. xhtml-file and bean are prepared as almost every example in the web shows.

I tried with and without Pretty Filter in `web.xml`, `allowCasualMultipartParsing` in `context.xml`, and a handful of other possible workarounds. None of them seemed to work (i.e. I can't read the file properties inside the bean).

Is there a solution that works 100%?

Comment: Are you implying that it works fine when you remove every single bit of PrettyFaces altogether and/or when you run it on a different server than GlassFish?

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use these two (for my bachelor thesis). So I don't know exactly if it works otherwise. :-(

Comment: Uh, it's just to test and exclude, so that we know where to focus for the root cause of the problem.

Comment: I've the same problem. You can use Prettyface on any other page than the one you upload files from and it's gonna work indeed.

Comment: Apparently a possible work around is to force primefaces to use common file upload. I'm searching how to do this and will respond if it works when I find how to.

Comment: I read about putting the actual upload on another page and including it via iFrame on the desired page. How does this work?

Comment: So, it's definitely caused by PrettyFaces? Then don't sit back doing nothing with regard to PrettyFaces. Post a bug report at their homepage, so that they can investigate and fix it for the next release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a sufficient solution, was posted here on stackoverflow.com before: [Fileupload and PrettyFaces and JSF 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943066/fileupload-and-prettyfaces-and-jsf-2-2)

Not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Prettier would be to report it to them so that they are informed about this bug and can fix it accordingly.