# Primefaces File Upload Stop Working After I have added PrettyFaces

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2, prettyfaces

First of all, the technologies I am using `Primefaces 6.1` ,`PrettyFaces 3.3.3` and `Wildfly 11`. I simply want to upload a file to my database with Primefaces 
`<p:fileUpload>` component. Here is the code snippet I have used.

```
<h:form>
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{imageopbean.uploadImage}"  mode="advanced" auto="true" style="display:none;" oncomplete="uppicture()" styleClass="imageUploadButton" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" >
          <f:attribute name="uniqueid" value="#{profileBean.theUser.userId}"/>
     </p:fileUpload>
</h:form>
```

it was working before I have used PrettyFaces library. Now, it doesn't invoke the `fileUploadListener`. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked-or-uploaded) question and some other solutions. But I can't make them work. What am I doing wrong? Here is the other parts of my code. Thanks.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>extranet</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>
        <param-value>2048576</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </context-param>  

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>primeFacesFileUploadFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>primeFacesFileUploadFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern />
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping> 
        <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
        <param-value>commons</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            60
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>    

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error-404.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/login</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/login</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

**ImageBean.java**

```
@Named("imageopbean")
@RequestScoped
public class ImageBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private ImageManager imageManager;

    /**
     *
     * @param event
     */
    public void uploadImage(FileUploadEvent event) {
        System.out.println("UPLOAD WORK");
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: If you 'automagically' have the PrettyFaces filter added (by adding the jar), maybe you need to add some explicit ordering (the order **is** relevant as you can read in the post you link to in the question, #1 in 'troubleshooting')

Comment: I added a little additional comment to the #1 in the duplicate. Does it help you?

Comment: I am using a web filter with annotation,  so you mean that the web filter may consume the upload request?

Comment: something like that yes or access at least some parts of th request that it is not fully or in the right format for the uploadfilter

Comment: I update my web.xml still not working. You can check out the question @Kukeltje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried most of the filter combinations in web.xml and nothing has worked.
I have found this,

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22985419/1562723

and I have deleted everything that I inserted in `web.xml` and `pom.xml`.
Here is the solution again:

1- Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<h:fom>` tag

2- Edit the script according to your JSF page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("form[enctype='multipart/form-data']").attr("action","#{request.contextPath}/test/fileupload.xhtml");
    });
</script>
```

Thats all..