# Primefaces fileUpload not working

Tags: primefaces

I have problems with p:fileUpload . 
I have this code and I have implemented everything that says PrimeFaces Guide and just not working. The FileUpload buttons do nothing.

XHTML

```
 <p:fileUpload
                        fileUploadListener="#{crearSitiosControlador.handleFileUpload}"
                        mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" update="messages"
                        sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="5" uploadLabel="Subir"
                        cancelLabel="Cancelar" label="Seleccionar"
                        invalidSizeMessage="Tamaño permitido 1MB"
                        invalidFileMessage="Archivo no permitido"
                        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
                    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
```

JAVA

```
 public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {  
        foto =  event.getFile();    
        fotoByte= new byte[(int) foto.getSize()];
        fotoByte = event.getFile().getContents();   

        try {       
            FileInputStream docu = new FileInputStream((File) event.getFile());
            // Leemos los bytes del archivo y a la vez se van insertando en el
            // array de bytes creado.
            int numBytes = docu.read(fotoByte);
            docu.close(); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("No se ha encontrado el archivo.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No se ha podido leer el archivo.");
        }

    }
```

WEBXML

```
      <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>auto|native|commons</param-value>
  </context-param> 

  <filter>
  <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
  org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter  
  </filter-class>  
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: And do you have a form ?

Comment: Yes and I put this.
<h:form  enctype="multipart/form-data" >

Comment: Your <param-value> looks strange to me, I would think you're supposed to pick 1 of the 3 options

Comment: Yeah you right , the <param-value> was wrong. Only one option is fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please review this, I solved similar problem whit this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked-or-uploaded