# File upload with advanced mode not working

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, appfuse

I'm trying to add advanced mode of FileUpload in Appfuse project and i followed this link: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/multiple.xhtml.

I add it but when in choose my files, there is no files displayed in growl tag and the upload and cancel button steel disable.

In the terminal of my navigator i have this error : TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Can you help me plzz 
Thanks

Comment: I followed this link: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/multiple.xhtml.

Comment: Do you have h:head in the page? It's gonna be guessing without any code

Comment: Do you update web.xml?

Comment: I add the h:head in tje page but steel not working. @Mathew: Whitch update i have to do in web.xml ?

Comment: it work now wheen i change <js>classpath:META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js</js> to <js>classpath:META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js</js> in wro.xml but when i click on upload file there is no call to the method fileUploadListener="#{fileUpload.handleFileUpload}" no thing happen. @JaqenH'ghar

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked

Answer (score 0):

the showcase has a bug
you you need to declare enctype with the value multipart/form-data 
Example

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
 <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
                  multiple="true" update="messages" sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="3" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />

    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
</h:form>
```