# Primefaces FileUpload not working in Spring Boot

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-boot, servlet-3.0

I'm running my JSF project launching it with Spring Boot and taking advantage of the whole Spring environment. The configuration is: Mojarra 2.2.8 + Primefaces 5.1 + Spring Boot 1.1.9. That's how my POM.xml file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.tesicnor.workplace.monitor.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.57</tomcat.version>
        <jsf.version>2.2.8</jsf.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

As it's specified above, I'm configuring the project to run in a tomcat 7.0.57 (Servlet 3.0 compatible) launcher. All the JSF functions are properly working, but the problem is I can't get the Primefaces `p:fileUpload` component work, neither the basic or the advanced versions. The file upload listener doesn't get invoked and no error thrown.

That's my bean's code:

```java
@ManagedBean
@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile()
                .getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        System.out.println("Uploaded!");
    }

}
```

And that's how my xhtml file looks like, under a template:

```xhtml
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{bean.handleFileUpload}" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Nothing special about the code at all, it must be a server configuration issue. When I drop the file and click on *upload*, the `FacesServlet` gets hit. So the request is performed and no javascript errors shown. But when I perform a debugging into the `InvokeApplicationPhase` class, where my method should be invoked, I find no events to be processed. So the `FileUploadEvent` is not being attached to the cycle.

Furthermore, that's the debugging stack of another project that properly performs the file upload with Tomcat 7 and that JSF version:

[image]

Here the `NativeFileUploadDecoder` is being called. However that's not happening in my Spring boot project and no method below `FileUpload#visitTree` is invoked.

I tried other choices and found out that when I use some `<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">` none of the action methods for components inside are invoked, even when I place a plain `h:commandButton`.

Comment: And the upload filter ? I'm not sure about spring-boot, maybe it has some filters in the way... I had the same issue when I used rewrite urls, I had to add to the `filter-mapping` of `PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter` a `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>`. it is a wild guess :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @HatemAlimam . I've been looking through documentation and actually PF has two upload options in its latest version, one relying on Servlet 3.0 spec and the other one on the `apache-commons` library. The filter is only required when using `apache-commons`. Finally I achieved getting it working that way, but not with the native spec. It would be interesting however to know the root cause of all of this. I'll post a small-demo project for people to be able to reproduce the issue..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I got it working using the Apache Commons library. Similarly that what we might do in a standard *web.xml* file, that's my context initializer:

```
@Bean
public ServletContextInitializer initializer() {
    return new ServletContextInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
                throws ServletException {
            servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.THEME", "bluesky");
            servletContext.setInitParameter(
                    "javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS", "true");
            servletContext.setInitParameter(
                    "com.sun.faces.expressionFactory",
                    "com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl");
            servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.UPLOADER",
                    "commons");
        }
    };
}
```

I explicitly tell Primefaces to use the *commons* uploader, like said in docs (the other choice is to use *native*, which is not working).

Then, just adding this two dependencies to the project, we're ready to go:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I keep the thread opened for some response based in the *native* mode.

**See also:**

- [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked or UploadedFile is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked)

Comment: Combining both answers worked for me with PF5.3. Thanks! Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Combining both answers worked for me as well PF 6.1 Spring boot 1.5.8. Many thanks I lost a few days of my wife searching for the solution.

Answer (score 4):

It could be also necessary to transfer xml filter configuration to Java-based Config :

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

to your @Configuration

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean FileUploadFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(new org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter());
    registration.setName("PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter");
    return registration;
}
```

in combination with the above answer it work for me

Comment: Did it work for the native way? I mean, having `servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.UPLOADER",
                    "native");` in your java configuration. This configuration is expected to work without the FileUpload filter.

Answer (score 4):

Just to put my two cents, with Spring boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Primefaces 6.0, OCP Soft rewrite 2.0.12.Final, JSF 2.1.29-08 and application deployed on Tomcat 8, I also need to disable spring hiddenHttpMethodFilter.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean hiddenHttpMethodFilterDisabled(
        @Qualifier("hiddenHttpMethodFilter") HiddenHttpMethodFilter filter) { 
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    filterRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

I have spent with this issue almost two days and as last thing I have tried to disable spring filters one by one, so I hope it will help someone.

Comment: The upload worked running the app in my IDE (irrespective of `packaging` setting in `pom.xml`) after using @Xtreme Biker's solution. However as a `war` deployed in tomcat, it didn't work. Adding your solution too did it for me. Thanks