# h:inputFile setter and action not invoked anymore since adding Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsf, file-upload

I work with Spring Boot 2.4.5 and JSF 2.2.20.

The `h:inputFile` is not working anymore since adding Spring Boot. The action method is not called, also the setter is not called.

I have written the following backing bean:

```
package com.dpdhl.gmppp.portal.webapp;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Component("uploadTestController")
@Scope("request")
public class UploadTestController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Part file1;

    private String message;

    public String uploadFile() throws IOException {
        boolean file1Success = false;
        if (file1 != null && file1.getSize() > 0) {
            file1Success = true;
        }
        if (file1Success) {
            setMessage("File successfully uploaded");
        } else {
            setMessage("Error, select atleast one file!");
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public Part getFile1() {
        return file1;
    }
    
    public void setFile1(Part file1) {
        this.file1 = file1;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

and this view:

```
<h2>Select and upload a file</h2>
<p>
    <h:outputText value="#{uploadTestController.message}"
                  rendered="#{!empty uploadTestController.message}"></h:outputText>
    <h:form prependid="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h:panelGrid>
            <h:inputFile value="#{uploadTestController.file1}"></h:inputFile>
            <h:commandButton action="#{uploadTestController.uploadFile()}"
                             value="Upload"></h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p>
```

If I use JSF without Spring Boot, then it works.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Did it ever work? How did you configure JSF and SpringBoot do you use JoinFaces?

Comment: No, it has never worked. No I dont use JoinFaces.

Comment: Spring Boot does not support JSF out of the box. You need to configure it and there you can use http://joinfaces.org/

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with JoinFaces either, do you have an example?

Comment: No but what do you mean by "doesn't work" Do you get an error message or what happens?

Comment: No, no error message. The Setter from the "private Part file1" is not called and the "uploadFile()" action is not called.

I think the --> enctype="multipart/form-data" is the problem... but without Spring Boot it works.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27552227/primefaces-fileupload-not-working-in-spring-boot

Comment: Thank you, but this is an Primefaces example, i dont use Primefaces. I try to use pure JSF.