# PrimeFaces 6 FileUploadFilter configuration with Spring Boot embedded Jetty

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, spring-boot, servlet-filters

`org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter` does not registered to my application, unless I define `FileUploadFilter` explicitly in my spring configuration like;

```
   @Bean
   FileUploadFilter fileUploadFilter() {
      return new FileUploadFilter();
   }
```

Referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked-or-uploaded);

> If you're however not using JSF 2.2 yet and you can't upgrade it
>   (should be effortless when already on a Servlet 3.0 compatible
>   container), then you need to manually register the below PrimeFaces
>   file upload filter in web.xml (it will parse the multi part request
>   and fill the regular request parameter map so that FacesServlet can
>   continue working as usual)

Conversely I have javax.faces in my classpath: `org.glassfish:javax.faces:jar:2.2.13:compile`. (and mojarra impl)

Should we go manually with this? Or else It can not be detected and registered automatically, we have to register a manual configuration to [joinfaces](https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces)

**UPDATE**: Actually this is not directly relevant to registration of `FileUploadFilter`. Embedded jetty in spring-boot does not pick up annotated configurations example of which `FacesServlet` has a `@MultipartConfig` annotation. I have opened an issue to spring-boot for that:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6681

Comment: The case is that; I want to choose `commons` as my uploader and expect `FileUploaderFilter` to picked up and registered to servlet context. Is there a  condition which I miss and additionally do to get it registered?

Comment: @BalusC The issue has actually related with spring boot with embedded jetty. Jetty embedded in spring does not configured to pick up `@MultipartConfig` classes

Comment: @BalusC updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6680 will fix the issue. `WebServletHandler` will pick up `@MultipartConfig` annotated classes.