# Primefaces Mobile p:fileupload upload method not called

Tags: spring, jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working on a web application for mobile devices where a user can upload a file (image) on several occasions.

Since I am using the Primefaces mobile renderkit, I have to use Primefaces' simple `p:fileupload`without ajax.

The Problem:
When I want to upload an Image I can select the file (components are rendered correctly) and then hit the "Upload" button. After I hit "Upload", the page refreshes but `myBean.saveImage()` is never called. `myBean.fileUploadController.setFile` isn't called either. I don't get any error messages in the Netbeans console and neither in Chromes JS Console.

So far I tried to use the native HTTP Servlet Upload which is supported by primefaces since version 5.0 and the old commons.fileupload way - same result.

I followed [this great guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8880083/2703623) to troubleshoot `p:fileupload`but I still get the same result after doing everything suggested in the guide.

I created a fileuploadtest.xhtml page to test the upload functionality which looks like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile">
     
    <f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" />
     
    <h:head>
 
    </h:head>
     
    <h:body>
         
        <pm:page>
            <pm:header title="Title"></pm:header>
             
            <pm:content>
                <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p:fileUpload value="#{myBean.fileUploadController.file}" mode="simple"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Upload" ajax="false" action="#{myBean.saveImage}"/>
                </h:form>
            </pm:content>
 
            <pm:footer title="Footer"></pm:footer>
        </pm:page>
    </h:body>
     
</html>
```

Here is my bean and my `FileUploadController` class:

MyBean.java:

```
    @Component
    @Scope("session")
    @Named
    public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    
        @Autowired(required = true)
        private FileUploadController fileUploadController;
    
        //Bunch of unrelated methods
    
        public void saveImage() {
             this.fileUploadController.upload();
             //some more code after upload() is complete
        }
        //getters&setters
    }
```

FileUploadController.java:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class FileUploadController {

    private UploadedFile file;
    
    public boolean upload() {
        if (file != null) {
            //upload here
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
        
    <description>Webflow Archetype</description>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:/spring/applicationContext.xml,/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Causes Facelets to refresh templates during development -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>cupertino</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Define partial state saving as true/false.</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Custom MarqueeComponent -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/marquee-taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>BootsFaces_USETHEME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>


  

    <filter>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/ *</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Allows Jetty to serve Faces applications -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

 

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/ *</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
        <param-value>commons</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>   
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
   
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>180</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <secure>true</secure>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
    
   
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value/>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        <multipart-config>
            <max-file-size>10485760</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>20971520</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>5242880</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Map all /spring requests to the Dispatcher Servlet for handling -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>at.managementpartners.icosysmobile.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    
    <!-- <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GetClientHostnameServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>at.managementpartners.icosysmobile.web.util.GetClientHostnameServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet> -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>at.managementpartners.icosysmobile.web.util.FileServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
   
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/spring/ *</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  
    <!-- Faces Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
        <multipart-config>
            <max-file-size>10485760</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>20971520</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>5242880</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Faces Servlet Mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/ *</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/ *</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/do/ *</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!--servlet>
        <servlet-name>Primefaces Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Primefaces Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/ *</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping-->
    <!-- Welcome files -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/ *</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/files/ *</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <trim-directive-whitespaces>false</trim-directive-whitespaces>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

I configured this web.xml to work with commons.fileupload and not with the HTTP Servlet native Upload functionality.

Please note that I had to seperate ´/*´ with a space (´/ *´) so that the rest of my code wouldn't get formatted as a comment. (If there is a smarter way to do this please don't hesitate to tell me)

My web application relies on the following technologies/libraries:

JSF 2.2.9

HTTP Servlet 3.0.1

Spring MVC

Spring Webflow

Primefaces 6.0 with `<f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" />`

Omnifaces 1.5

Bootsfaces 0.8.1

Netbeans as IDE

For testing and debugging purposes I deploy the app to Jetty 8.1.5 via Netbeans.

However I tried deploying the app to a Tomcat server as well with the same result.

Please forgive the long post, I just wanted to include everything that seemed remotely useful. If you need anything else please let me know.

Thank you very much in advance.

## EDIT:

It appears that my problem does not have anything to do directly with `p:fileupload` but rather with my `p:commandButton`s not invoking any action event at all, when I disable ajax. To test this, I added the `ajax="false"` attribute to one of my comandButtons on another page. As soon as I added it, my commandButton stopped working and it just refreshed the site but never handled the event specified in the `action` attribute. Does anyone have an idea why my commandbuttons stop working with `ajax="false"`?

## Edit2

I posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39391056/2703623) since I discovered that the problem is related to something slightly different

Comment: Why don't you call the `upload()` method directly without going through `saveImage()`

Comment: because `saveImage()` does someting else after calling `upload()`. I should have clarified that.

Comment: is there any error log ?

Comment: No, no error log at all. Chrome's JS console doesn't show anything either.

Comment: what about the IDE's console ?

Comment: As I said, I don't get any error anywhere. Not in IDE's console, in the log files or Chrome

Comment: Regarding your MyBean.java, why is its name different from the class `QuickAssessmentBean` ? and to use it as a managed bean you gotta add the `@Named` CDI annotation along with `@Scope("session")` Spring  annotation you have there.

Comment: I added `@Named` (please take a look if I understood correctly what you meant) and I corrected the bean name (I renamed it for this quesition and forgot to rename the Class name).
Nevertheless it unfortunately did not solve my problem.

Comment: I read you Edit, can you confirm that the file was set, like write a `System.out.print("setting file")` in your `setFile`. Since the problem is in the command button , I propose you either switch to `<h:commandButton>` or you dispose of it and add `auto="true"` in your `<p:fileUpload>` so the file is uploaded automatically

Comment: `setFile()` is never called since it would only be called once I submit the form (as this is a non-ajax request), which it can't since `p:commandButton`does not work in my app with `ajax="false"`. I obviously cannot add `auto="true"` since my `p:fileupload` must work with primefaces mobile.  `auto="true"`only works with `mode="advanced"`, not the simple mode.

Comment: try substituting `action` with `actionListener`, if it doesn't work , try `<h:commandButton>` instead of `<p:commandButton>`

Comment: I did try all of these things already as they are quite obvious and suggested in several other fileupload related questions on stackoverflow. `h:commandbutton` shows exactly the same behaviour as `p:commandButton` and switching between `action` and `actionListener` does not change anything (besides the fact that one should not use the Listener for this kind of operation).