# CommandButton does not fire action when <h:form> includes enctype="multipart/form-data"

Tags: spring, file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2.2, enctype

I have already posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350217/primefaces-mobile-pfileupload-upload-method-not-called) regarding `p:fileupload`a few days ago. After digging deeper into this problem I realized that my main issue seems to be of a different origin and I therefore opened up a new question.

I am developing a web app (JSF2.2) for **mobile devices** where a user can upload a file at several occasions. I want to use Primefaces' `p:fileupload`component for this job which does not seem to work. I discovered that the problem seems to be connected with the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute of `<h:form>`. Whenever I have this attribute in my form, commandButton does not call the bean method specified in its `action=""`attribute (neither when using `actionListener=""`). When I delete the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute everything works as it should except  for the file upload obiously.

For testing and debugging purposes I created an `uploadTest.xhtml`page
that looks currently as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"         
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" />

    <h:head>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="dasistmeineform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:fileUpload value="#{uploadBean.uploadedFile}" mode="simple"/>
            <p:commandButton action="#{uploadBean.upload}" ajax="false" value="upload" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

To exclude Primefaces from the list of possible error causes I created another test page as well where I only used `<h:inputFile>` and `<h:commandButton>` and no primefaces components. This gives me the same result.

Here is my UploadBean.java:

```
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

@ManagedBean
@RequestSoped
public class UploadBean {

    private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

    public UploadedFile getUploadedFile() {
        return uploadedFile;
    }

    public void setUploadedFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
        this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
    }

    public void upload() {
        if (this.getUploadedFile() != null) {
            System.out.println("Hurray!");
        }
    }



}
```

My personal guess is that this issue has something to do with the way the application is set up or how JSF is implemented in the app. To troubleshoot this I followed the [JSF set up guide](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) by @BalusC. Moreover I followed some of his other troubleshooting guides, including [how to troubleshoot p:fileupload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8880083/2703623) and a [list of possible causes why a bean method is not invoked when pressing h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2120183/2703623). Nothing has helped so far unfortunately.

I get no error in the Netbeans console and neither in Chrome's developer console. After I press the upload button I can see the HTTP request with the developer tools. The Response has the code 200 so everything should have worked correctly on the HTTP side, right?

The web application uses the following components:

JSF 2.2.13 (Mojarra)

Spring Webflow

Spring MVC

Primefaces 5.3

Omnifaces 1.3

Bootsfaces 0.9.1

The application is deployed and tested on a Jetty 8.1.5 Server directly via Netbeans.

To check if I have all the necessary dependencies downloaded, I'll include the relevant party of my pom.xml (I use maven):

```
 <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I included `commons-io` and `commons-fileupload` to test if `p:fileupload` would work with the old (prior to Servlet 3.0) way, which it didn't.

Here is my web.xml: (please note that I also tested without the `context-param` and `filter` entries for `p:fileupload` without success):

-->

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <description>Webflow Archetype</description>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
        <param-value>auto</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:/spring/applicationContext.xml,/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Causes Facelets to refresh templates during development -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Disable/Enable PF/M default theme:   -->
    <!--    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.mobile.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>none</param-value>
    </context-param>-->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>cupertino</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Define partial state saving as true/false.</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Custom MarqueeComponent -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/marquee-taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>BootsFaces_USETHEME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value/>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        <!--        <multipart-config>
            <max-file-size>10485760</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>20971520</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>5242880</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>-->
    </servlet>
    <!-- Map all /spring requests to the Dispatcher Servlet for handling -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>at.managementpartners.icosysmobile.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>at.managementpartners.icosysmobile.web.util.FileServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>



    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/spring/ *</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>at.managementpartners.icosysmobile.web.util.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Serves static resource content from .jar files such as spring-faces.jar -->
    <!-- Map all /resources requests to the Resource Servlet for handling -->
    <!-- Faces Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
        <!--        <multipart-config>
            <max-file-size>10485760</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>20971520</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>5242880</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>-->
    </servlet>
    <!-- Faces Servlet Mapping -->
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/ *</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/ *</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!--   
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/do/ *</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    -->    

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- servlet>
        <servlet-name>Primefaces Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Primefaces Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping -->
    <!-- Welcome files -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!--<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GetClientHostnameServlet</servlet-name>        
        <url-pattern>/GetClientHostnameServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> -->

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/files/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>ClickjackFilterSameOrigin</filter-name>
        <filter-class>at.managementpartners.icosysmobile.web.util.ClickjackFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>mode</param-name>
            <param-value>SAMEORIGIN</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ClickjackFilterSameOrigin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/ *</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/ *</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Allows Jetty to serve Faces applications -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!--    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>-->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/ *</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <!-- Lebenszeit der Session in Minuten (480 min = 8 Stunden; 180 min = 3 Stunden)    -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>180</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <secure>true</secure>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>ttf</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff2</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-woff2</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>eot</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <!-- The front controller of this Spring Web application, responsible for handling all application requests -->



    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <trim-directive-whitespaces>false</trim-directive-whitespaces>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errors/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errors/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errors/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>402</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errors/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errors/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errors/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Please note that I had to seperate ´/*´ with a space (´/ *´) so that the rest of my code wouldn't get formatted as a comment. (If there is a smarter way to do this please don't hesitate to tell me)

Could Spring's MVC Dispatcher Servlet somehow interfere with the upload functionality of Servlet 3.0?

Am I using other components that break the standard behaviour of Servlet 3.0 file upload?

Is my project even set up correctly?

Thank you very much. Even a little hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Comining spring-mvc and jsf in the same webapp is 'strange'. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744910/using-jsf-as-view-technology-of-spring-mvc

Comment: So if I understood the contents of this link correctly, the whole way how this project was set up was completely wrong and two different technologies that are not supposed to work with eachother werde mixed up?
Well the thing is this application is huge. Rebuilding it would take probably more than a year. Strangely, fileUpload is the first thing that caused such an (to date) unresolveable error. Is this really the result of this mix-up or rather of a mistake int he configuration made by me?

Comment: I am still stuck with this problem. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide us a "reproducer"? A small program you can upload on GitHub (or a similar platform) so the StackOverflow community can download your code and analyze the code? Ideally, such a reproducer is very small - just your Java bean, the JSF file, the pom.xml, the web.xml and the faces-config.xml. But don't make it too small, it still has to run.