# Advanced fileUpload get the file null with Primefaces

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

Environment:

- Primefaces 6.1
- JavaEE 7
- Wildfly 10
- JSF 2.2

when I click the button after having selected the file, the file var is null.

**Test.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <title>Application</title>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>

            <h:form id="frmTest" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <ui:include src="template/messages.xhtml" />
                <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
       update="messages" sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="3" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

**TestBean.java**

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class TestBean implements Serializable {
...
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        UploadedFile file = event.getFile();//file is null
        FacesUtils.addInfoMessage("Succesful" + file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        System.out.println("Succesful" + event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
}
...
```

Comment: have you already have a look to `<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">` as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked-or-uploaded ?

Comment: yes, I already bumped into that question in stackoverflow but nothing worked. The event is not even called.

Answer (score -1):

You should remove or fill the `update=""` attribute from your `fileUpload` component. It "redirects" the files to a component after upload.

Comment: I tested it and it didn't work either.