# p:fileUpload in simple mode returns null pointer error

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I have tried to do simple file upload using JSF 2.1 and Primefaces 3.5.I can attach the file in UI.When I click submit button after attached the file it returns null pointer exception.

upload2.xhtml

```
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Journaldev Tutorial</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadManagedBean.file}"  mode="simple"></p:fileUpload>
                <p:separator/>
                <h:commandButton value="Upload" ajax="false" action="#{fileUploadManagedBean.dummyAction}"></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Testty3</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/upload2.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <multipart-config/>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/icefaces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
<!--   <filter>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping> -->
<filter>
 <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
     <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<!--    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param> -->
    <context-param>
  <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
  <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener> -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
    the rendered HTML output.
    If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
    that submits the corresponding form.
    If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
    will be added as url parameters.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
    i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
    influence the HTML code.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
    former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
    with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
    if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
    Default is 'false'
</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.icefaces.coalesceResources</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.icefaces.strictSessionTimeout</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.REFRESH_TRANSIENT_BUILD_ON_PSS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.REFRESH_TRANSIENT_BUILD_ON_PSS_PRESERVE_STATE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>png</extension>
    <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

FileUploadManagedBean.java

```
package com.journaldev.prime.faces.beans;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class FileUploadManagedBean {
    UploadedFile file;

    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        System.out.println("getFile()");
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        System.out.println("setFile()");
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String dummyAction(){
        System.out.println("Uploaded File Name Is " + file.getFileName());
        //System.out.println("Uploaded File Name Is :: "+file.getFileName()+" :: Uploaded File Size :: "+file.getSize());
        return "";
    }
}
```

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Error calling action method of component with id j_id_5:__9
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:119)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1013)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:284)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1302)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:745)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareELException: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:108)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:72)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:268)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.journaldev.prime.faces.beans.FileUploadManagedBean.dummyAction(FileUploadManagedBean.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
```

In my browser it shows javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException. Can some one Please help to figure out the error

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it search for duplicate Q/A and see if they helped and if not check/state why they dud nor help. See [ask]

Comment: Is there any additional error / warning in your log file?

Comment: I checked with similar issues but it didn't work. There is only one console log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked or UploadedFile is null / throws an error / not usable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked-or-uploaded)