# PrimeFaces FileUploadFilter after Migration from SpringBoot 2 to SpringBoot 3

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, primefaces

I would like to migrate my SpringBoot 2 Primefaces 12 application to SpringBoot 3.

In SpringBoot 2 Filter was defined in:

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
```

The package was changed in SpringBoot 3 to:

```
import jakarta.servlet.Filter;
```

now I have defined:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean fileUploadFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(new org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter());
    registration.setName("PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter");
    return registration;
}
```

setFilter requires jakarta Filter, but primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter is javax Filter

Is there any workaround ? Does Primefaces provide also jakarta filter ?

pom:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.faces-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.SP1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>31.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-parsers-standard-package</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xyz.capybara</groupId>
        <artifactId>clamav-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotbugs-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I don't know, and i'm not sure my question isn't stupid, but do you actually need that filter?

Comment: it seems it's not needed since PrimeFaces 5? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked-or-uploaded

Comment: Yes don't use FileUploadFilter just use JSF Native mode. See: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/fileupload?id=getting-started-with-fileupload

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked before and do not use FileUploadFilter with Jakarta as its no longer needed.

See: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/fileupload?id=getting-started-with-fileupload