PrimeFaces 7.0 FileUpload file is null
Hey i am stuck at this problem for a long time and couldnt find a solution for it.
Now after my vacation the problem is still waiting for me and i have no clue what to do anymore and motivation. I dont get help from my team after asking several times and present them what i did.
My goal is to Upload a file from a xhtml class into the Bean Faclet.(@ManagedBean)
What i used: The PrimeFaces Basic Upload Simple/Advanced from the showcase
The Problem: The mask is shown correct, i can choose the file and it will be shown in the field.
When i want to upload it, i get the error, that the value, file in the Bean is null.
Error: java.lang.NullpointerException. Cannot invoke "org.primefaces model.UploadFile.getFileName()" beacuse the return value of  xxx.getFile()" is null
The Request seems to be fine in the Germanword "Nutzlast" tab i can see the file name.
I know there are a view other posts with the same problem and i already tried their solution, but it didnt work out for me.
My setup:

PrimeFaces 7.0
Spring Boot
Tomcat 9.0.38

I tried different solution approaches:

I googled here but none of the solutions helped me further

context, filter, dependency


I did it step by step, also tried the inputText just to be sure something is given to the Bean and it works.
I tried the Simple and Advanced mode
Debugging of course, step by step, but there is no error in the console beside it is null when i try to read the file.
I tried a different PrimeFaces version
I added the config in the web.xml and the filters

<context-param>
   <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
   <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>
 
<filter>
 <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>
  org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
 </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>


Added dependencys :

<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

Part of my code, i cant share all. Its very simple
xHtml:
<h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5" style=margin-left:20px; margin top:30px">
  <h:form enctype ="multipart/form-data"> 
    <p:outputLabel value ="File: "/>
    <p:fileUpload value ="#{ImportBean.file}" mode ="simple" />
    <p:commandButton value="Generien" ajax="false" action="#{ImportBean.createFile()}" />
  </h:form>
</h:panelGrid>
   

Bean:
@ManageBean(Value ="ImportBean")
@RequestScope 

public class  ImportFileBean {

  private UploadedFile file;
 
    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }
 
    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
 
   
public void createFile(){

String filename = getFile().getFilename();
LOG.info(filename);
}



I think you are getting a nullpointer when you access the file object from your bean. The annotation for the class of a managed bean with the @ManageBean annotation would be with the name attribute, not value, value is used when managing a bean within another with the @ManagedProperty annotation.
@ManageBean(name="importBean")
@RequestScope 
public class  ImportFileBean {

  private UploadedFile file;
 
    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }
 
    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}

Servlet-name should match the configured name of the JSF servlet which is "Faces Servlet" in this case. Check that servlet-name is defined the same as filter-mapping:
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>


I understood that value ="#{ImportBean.file}"  gives the value to the File attribute in the Bean over the Name. It does the same when i use InputText and this works.

I edited the question with something else you can check. Also, Maybe this link can help you, a lot of information is detailed depending on the version of primefaces used and the file upload mode (simple or advanced)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked-or-uploaded/8880083#8880083
